# Spark Java: Add vector values as new column in DataFrame by taking values from different columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Let say we have Data frame with 4 columns A,B,C,D. Now what I want is to combine B,C,D column values as Vector and Add them as new column i.e. Column E into existing data frame. I want to do this directly within data frame without converting it to RDD and then adding vector value to RDD and then transforming back it to dataframe. As this is not good solution.

So, I want some Java solution to do it directly within Dataframe API.

Answer (score 0):

For this Scenario You can use `VectorAssemBler`
Here is the Sample Code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler;
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT;
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes.*;

StructType schema = createStructType(new StructField[]{
  createStructField("id", IntegerType, false),
  createStructField("hour", IntegerType, false),
  createStructField("mobile", DoubleType, false),
  createStructField("userFeatures", new VectorUDT(), false),
  createStructField("clicked", DoubleType, false)
});
Row row = RowFactory.create(0, 18, 1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 10.0, 0.5), 1.0);
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(row), schema);

VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(new String[]{"hour", "mobile", "userFeatures"})
  .setOutputCol("features");

Dataset<Row> output = assembler.transform(dataset);
System.out.println(output.select("features", "clicked").first());
```

For futher Usage check this link below
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/ml-features.html#vectorassembler

Hope  this works